# Magento 2.2.0 checkout regenerate session id very slow

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.0

Session saving in memcache. Сheckout page is load 16sec. From xdebug profiling i found out that the problem in function Magento\Framework\Session->regenerateId() session_start() exec 15 sec.

Why it so?

p.s if session save path set to file then problem is solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably due to this core bug, which was patched in Magento 2.2.2:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12385